# Installing Ubuntu Again

Tags: kubuntu, uninstall, remote-desktop

I installed ubuntu last week on my computer. The way I did it was creating a partition on my HDD and then I used the windows installation of ubuntu to installed there. After I did it, I restart my computer and try to boot ubuntu, but it did not work. So I tried to go into my windows 7 boot again. On the booting process I got the message that my computer crash or had some kind of error so I choose the option to recover my system from a rally point, after I did it; the partition that I created was gone. So I turned my computer of and turned it on to see if the dual boot screen was gone, but it was still there. After that I tried many different was to erase the dual boot.

I also tried to install ubuntu again, but the installer is not letting me do it because the file of Wubi still in my system. I would like to know if some can help me with this, so I can erase those files, and install ubuntu again on my computer.

I have windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the official Ubuntu wiki topic on uninstalling WUBI. If I understand your question properly this should work and allow you to completely reinstall Ubuntu. 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation

Comment: see also http://askubuntu.com/q/3257