# How to remove ubuntu

Tags: wubi, uninstall

So I originally installed ubuntu to a flash drive with wubi. Later I removed it from the flash drive and reinstalled a new version (still with wubi) but this time to my hard drive. Both still show up when I turn on my computer is there a way I can get rid of the first one (since it doesn't work anymore)?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find all wubi related answers solved: [How do I remove the Ubuntu boot option created by Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3257/how-do-i-remove-the-ubuntu-boot-option-created-by-wubi)

Comment: the speaker is saying about wubi and windows boot menu not grub